# Convenient way to create latex-tables from python-xarray

Tags: latex, python-xarray

l am looking for a convenient way to bring values from my xarray dataset to a latex table. Keeping the long name [units] of the values and also being able to style the latex table freely is something I didn't find any guides on yet. What method are the fellow users of xarray, who are publishing in latex, using?